# Trying to move my image all the way to the left without using a negative margin

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with a few of my images. The Problem originally occurred when I resized my browser and my logo would be half cut, so you could only see half of it. Of course, it was frustratingly simple. I just had to remove margin-left{ negative value; } Now I am having problems moving my content a few pixels to the left without using the above. I could put it on JS fiddle, but I don't think that would help since the images won't show up. I also don't want to use any positioning. I want to keep it in normal flow.

Any help appreciated!

```
<div id="rainbow">
<img src="images/rainbow.png" alt="rainbow gradient">
</div> 

<div id="header">
<p id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Bethan Rainforth a comedic dancer" >
</p>
</div>

<div class="danceleft">
<img src="images/danceleft.png" alt="dancer to the left kicking">
</div>
```

I still have margin-left as you can see but plan on deleting it once I can figure out how to move the image to the left

```
#rainbow img {
width: 149.2%;
margin-left: -190px;
margin-right: 20%;
}

#logo img {
width: 320px;
margin-top: -60px;
}

div.danceleft img {
width: 20%;
margin-bottom: -56%;

}
```

Comment: You can use dummy images from LoremPixel.com in a demo.

Comment: What about using `float`?

Comment: float just wraps the content around my image. I just want to move it to the left a few inches and keep it in place

Comment: `float:left; display:block`?

Answer (score 0):

for img display inline

```
text-align:left
```

for general

```
float:left
position:relative, absolute, fixed
padding-left
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using

```
position: relative;
left: -XXpx;
```

This will move the image to the left relative to the original position of the image.

Comment: he problem using this is that it doesn't follow normal flow and part of my image gets cut off when I resize the browser.